# Embedding password protected pdf's?

Tags: python, html, django

I have some pdf files which I would like to publish on my websites. I don't want them to be downloaded. Is there any way that I can publish those files as password protected such that they are automatically opened on the website but when someone downloads it they can't open unless they have the password?

Comment: try uploading that to google drive and post a link there so that only the people you explicitly share with can open it. for more information visit: https://www.steegle.com/websites/google-sites-howtos/embed-drive-pdf